# How to get 3 minutes future date?

Tags: date, busybox

I want to get the date 3 minutes on the future. For example, if "now" is

```
01-Jan-70 00:00:00 GMT
```

I want to get

```
01-Jan-80 00:03:00 GMT
```

How should I do it? I'm working with busybox linux.

Comment: I like how it's 3 minutes and 10 years... subtle!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With GNU `date` you can do it as simple as this:

```
date --date="3min"
```

But `busybox` seems not so smart (yet). The only reliable solution I came up with using `bb` is:

```
busybox date -D '%s' -d "$(( `busybox date +%s`+3*60 ))"
```

(you don't need the `busybox` parts if there is no other `date` implementation present)

If you want a formatted output, you could add this

```
busybox date -D '%s' +"%y%m%d%H%" -d "$(( `busybox date +%s`+3*60 ))"
```

Comment: I have not found why yet but this does not seem to be compatible with latest's alpine with busybox:
`docker run -it alpine ash -c 'busybox date -D "%s" -d "$(( "$(busybox date +%s)"+3*60 ))"'` returns `date: invalid date '1617211960'`

Comment: The correct syntax seems to be

```busybox date -d@"$(( `busybox date +%s`+3*60 ))" ```

Answer (score 11):

Working solution on alpine linux

```
date -d@"$(( `date +%s`+180))"
```

Comment: Please elaborate about your command, as to how it works and such. Also, why does not the original solution work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the date for +2 hours on busybox OS on my router
my command:

```
date "$(date +%m%d"$(( `date +%H`+2 ))"%M%Y.%S)"
```